# How to use Xdebug in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have a trouble to use debugger in my code, it's my first time to use debugger, I don't know that I am doing it the right way or not, but it is not working for me. it always show this message in variables section...

***Waiting for incoming connection with ide key '13001'***

I followed this step...

**1. my php.ini setting for xdebug**

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension="D:\XAMMPI\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.0-5.6-vc11.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=80 //i also try the default port (9000) here but it still not working
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

**2. I create the configuration setting for Debugger.**

[image: configuration setting]

**3. I apply the break point to code for testing**

[image: break point place]

I am using PhpStorm  2016.1

Any help will be appreciated

**UPDATE - 1**

[image]

Comment: 1) *"xdebug.remote_port=80"* -- this is wrong ... please read what that port number is used for before making such changes. https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings 2) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Comment: *"UPDATE - 1"* -- you are running **JavaScript** debugging session -- no wonder that PHP debug is not working here....

Answer (score 5):

Just **use my php.ini setting for xdebug**

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension="D:\XAMMPI\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.0-5.6-vc11.dll" ; copied this link based on your config.
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=10000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.idekey=
```

Then **install xDebug helper** for chrome:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc?hl=en

Then **change the IDE key to phpstorm**
[image: Change the IDE key to phpstorm]

After that, you should create a **PHP Remote Debug** and not **PHP Web Application**

Like the picture below.

[image]

On your settings. Which can be accessed using `Ctrl+Alt S`. Search for Debug port, and change it to 10000.

[image]

After that you should navigate to your extension in chrome and activate xDebug.

[image]

**And that's it. Happy Debugging :)**

Comment: Still not working... it is not showing any thing in Debugger like we normally see that in loop data is comming.. Please check update - 1 above.

Comment: @stackvr, noted. By the way, this should be helpful when setting up your debugger from scratch. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
Waiting for incoming connection with ide key '13001'
```

vs

```
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

you need to set proper idekey in PHPStorm, and change back ports to 9000. 80 is port for apache (http server), so it will not work as you've configured.

Look here to learn where to set the idekey in ide: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/run-debug-configuration-php-remote-debug.html